# How to catch error when copying file from USB and the USB is disconnected

Tags: c#, filesystems

I am facing problem about copying files from portable device. My app should run automatic copying and back up for firefighters. When I plug portable device, the app should recognize that action and start copying. Problem is when I will disconnect the device during copying. I am using

```
var t = Task.Run(() => { 
      System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFileBU, overwrite: true); 
});
t.Wait();
```

I have tryied all of this code in `try catch method`, but in visual studio I always get exception and falling the app.

Is there problem in the task run? Why the try catch method did not help?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Never, never, never use `Task.Wait()`. Always `await` a task.

Comment: @DavidG can I ask for reason?

Comment: Lots of resources out there if you have a google, but David Fowler has a nice repo discussing issues: https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskresult-and-taskwait

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` and `catch` statements to catch expectations.

Also just like @DavidG said, don't use `Task.Wait()` Instead you `await` a task

So this can be your code:

```
  var t = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
              System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFileBU, overwrite: true);
        }
    catch
        {
              SetBalloonTipDisconnected();
              fail = true;
        }
    });
```

Visit here for more information regarding the `try` and `catch` statements

[try and catch statements info](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/csharp/try-catch-in-csharp#:%7E:text=%20C%23%20try-catch%20Overview%20%201%20In%20try-catch,catch%20block%20with%20an%20appropriate%20exception...%20More%20)

Comment: My mistake in my question, I am using try - catch statements, I have to highlight it in my question.

Comment: Then what are you exactly trying to achieve then?